# kubuntu wallpaper settings disappear

Tags: kde, desktop-background, reset, slideshow

To render my system useable after upgrading to 11.10, I had to abandon gnome and install the KDE window manager.  This is mostly fine, but the *desktop wallpaper slideshow*  works for a few minutes and then gets reset to the default (fixed kubuntu splash background).  I can start up the slideshow again by right-clicking on the background and re-entering all the Desktop Settings, but then it just disappears again after a while.  What could be causing this?

***Oops!***   What I failed to realize was that KDE apparently uses an independent wallpaper setting for each desktop. I have 12, so some were set to the slideshow but others were still set to the default. Being accustomed to one common wallpaper setting for all desktops, I misinterpreted this as a global reset. *Sorry!*

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved by the OP:

> Oops!   What I failed to realize was that KDE apparently uses an
>   independent wallpaper setting for each desktop. I have 12, so some
>   were set to the slideshow but others were still set to the default.
>   Being accustomed to one common wallpaper setting for all desktops, I
>   misinterpreted this as a global reset. Sorry!